Error: code in generated R.java is too large
code in generated R.java is too large
how to fix it?
enter image description here
I tried to set intellisense.filesize to 25000，but it doesn't work
enter image description here
The error locates at 'id' class.
enter image description here
What else solutions can I try?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
